# convert column to string skipping np.NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

My series:

```
a = pd.Series(['asd',4, np.NaN])
```

If I do:

```
b = a.astype(str, skipna=True)
print(b)
print(b.isna().any())
```

```
>>>['asd', '4', 'nan']
>>> False
```

What am I doing wrong?

I would like it to be:

```
>>>['asd', '4', np.NaN]
>>> True
```

I know I could replace the 'nan' with np.NaN but that would be impractical when you have to do this many times.

Python v: 3.6.5

Comment: What's your expected output? It isn't clear to me

Comment: Just added an edit

Comment: Might be your `pandas` version. I ran your code and got `True` and a `NaN` that's not a string

Comment: work fine one my side at 0.25

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25353

Comment: Yeah, seems like my pandas version. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs as expected on my system (python 3.7, pandas 0.25). Probably you can try:

```
b = a.where(a.isna(), a.astype(str))
```

Output:

```
0    asd
1      4
2    NaN
dtype: object
```